Triying to migrate firebase from Legacy FCM API to HTTP v1 getting "Insufficient Permission"
I am following this tutorial: https://medium.com/@vc21496/migrating-from-legacy-fcm-apis-to-http-v1-api-in-php-63076c5aa212
Using 'google-auth-library' in typescript:
    const {JWT} = require('google-auth-library');

    var keys_lit  =  fs.readFileSync('./resources/firebase/service.json', {encoding:'utf8', flag:'r'});
    var keys = JSON.parse(keys_lit);

    const client = new JWT({
        email: keys.client_email,
        key: keys.private_key,
        scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging']
    });
    const url = `https://dns.googleapis.com/dns/v1/projects/${keys.project_id}`;
    const res = await client.request({url});
    console.log(res.data);

I got:

I saw the permissions and roles and i think that the account used in the json has the rigth to create tokens:

